# Is there some sort of hardware support required for the implementation of the scheduler?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduling

The state of the process at any given time consists of the processes in execution right? So at the moment say there are 4 userspace programs running on the processors. Now after each time slice, I assume control has to pass over to the scheduler so that the appropriate process can be scheduled next. What initiates this transfer of control? For me it seems like there has to be some kind of special timer/register in hardware that keeps count of the current time taken by the process since the process itself has no mechanism to keep track of the time for which it has executed... Is my intuition right??

Comment: `Is my intuition right??` partially, hardware timer initiates interrupt, which is handled by OS, in this handler it can schedule threads/process execution, this timer does not know anything about threads, OS knows

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this answer concerns the x86 architecture **only**.

There are different kinds of schedulers: preemptive and non-preemptive (cooperative).

**Preemptive schedulers** *preempt* the execution of a process, that is, initiate a context switch using a TSS (Task State Segment), which then performs a jump to another process. The process is stopped and another one is started.

**Cooperative schedulers** do not stop processes. They rely on the process, which give up the CPU in favor of the scheduler, also called "yielding," similar to user-level threads without kernel support.

Preemption can be accomplished in two ways: as the result of some I/O-bound action or while the CPU is at play.
Imagine you sent some instructions to the FPU. It takes some time until it's finished. Instead of sitting around idly, you could do something else while the FPU performs its calculations! So, as the result of an I/O operation, the scheduler switches to another process, possibly resuming with the preempted process right after the FPU is done.
 
However, regular preemption, as required by many scheduling algorithms, can only be implemented with some interruption mechanism happening with a certain frequency, independently of the process. A timer chip was deemed suitable and with the IBM 5150 (a.k.a. IBM PC) released in 1981, an x86 system was delivered, incorporating, inter alia, an Intel 8086, an Intel 8042 keyboard controller chip, the Intel 8259 PIC (Programmable Interrupt Controller), and the **Intel 8253 PIT (Programmable Interval Timer)**.

The i8253 connected, like a few other peripheral device, to the i8259. A couple of times in a second (18 Hz?) it issued an #INT signal to the PIC on IRQ 0 and after acknowledging and all the CPU was interrupted and a handler was executed.
That very handler could contain scheduling code, which decides on the next process to execute<sup>1</sup>.

Of course, we (most of us) are living in the 21<sup>st</sup> century by now and there's no IBM PC or one of its derivatives like the XT or AT used. The PIC has changed to the more sophisticated Intel 82093AA APIC to handle multiple processors/cores and for general improvement but the PIT has remained the same, I think, maybe in shape of some integrated version like the Intel AIP.

Cooperative schedulers do not need a regular interrupt and therefore no special hardware support (except maybe for hardware-supported multitasking). The process yields the CPU deliberately and if it doesn't, you have a problem. The reason as to why few OSes actually use cooperative schedulers: it poses a big security hole.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note, however, that OSes on the 8086 (mostly DOS) didn't have a real
scheduler. The x86 architecture only natively supported multitasking in the
hardware with the advent of one of the 80386 versions (SX, DX, and whatever). I just wanted to stress that the IBM 5150 was the first x86 system with a timer chip (and, of course, the first PC altogether).

Comment: The reason as to why few OSes actually use cooperative schedulers: their I/O performance is abysmally bad.

Comment: 'Preemption can only be implemented with some interruption mechanism happening with a certain frequency, independently of the process.' - incorrect.  Your explanation is dangerously misleading.

Comment: @MartinJames Better? You mean my overall explanation? If yes, I've probably gone off-topic a couple of times - but tell me more, please.

Answer (score 1):

Systems running an OS with preemptive schedulers, (ie. all those in common use), are, IME, all provided with a hardware timer interrupt that causes a driver to run and can change the set of running threads.

Such a timer interrupt is very useful for providing timeouts for system calls, sleep() functionality and other time-related functions.  It can also help share out the available CPU amongst ready threads when the system is overloaded, or the thread/s run on it are CPU-intensive, and so the number of ready threads exceeds the number of cores available to run them.

It is quite possible to implement a preemptive scheduler without any hardware timer, allowing the set of running threads to be secheduled upon software interrupts, (system calls), from threads that are already running, and all the other interrupts upon I/O completion from the peripheral drivers for disk, NIC, KB, mouse etc.  I've never seen it done though - the timer functionality is too useful:)

Comment: Multitasking without timer interrupts is not known as preemptive multitasking, but as cooperative multitasking.

Comment: @ninjalj completely incorrect and hugely misleading.  The timer interrupt is far from the only interrupt that may cause preemption.